# 404 error getting children of site in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am using Alfresco Community Edition 5.0.d and encountered a problem getting the folders of a site.

I can call http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/sites/sitename to obtain the nodeRef of a particular site, but after obtaining it, trying to access this webscript:

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/nodeID/children

gives me a 404 error, telling me that the script does not map to a WebScript.

Why isn't it working? If it really isn't allowed in my version of Alfresco, how else can I get the folders, or any children, of a site?

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace *nodeID* with the real nodeid in the form of hexadecimal string you obtained from the previous call.

Example:

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/94e777a3-393a-48d3-bb5e-f162d75cbd50/children
```

or using CMIS:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/i/94e777a3-393a-48d3-bb5e-f162d75cbd50/children
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, and got the 404, which is why I'm asking

Comment: Did you check exact case matching of the URL?

Comment: I've checked everything; the URL I'm trying looks like this: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/df7d2a4a-5dd9-497b-bdbc-0780db557e0b/children

Comment: I'm sure this URL is working at least till version 4.2.f

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if it was deprecated for version 5.0. Is there any other way I can access site content? Through another different API call or CMIS?

Comment: Give a try with the CMIS version